# Span of an equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, notation, terminology, roots

I use this term to denote a set of numbers of the form $\sum z_n x^n$, where $x$ is the solution of some polynomial $x^a=\sum z_ix^i$ for $i=0$ to $a-1$.

$a$, $i$, and the $z_j$ are all in $\mathbb{Z}$.

For example, “the span” of $a^3=7$ would be all numbers of the form $xa^2+ya+z$, $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $a^3=7$.

Is there a standard term for it?

Comment: I've edited the question.  They're all in Z.

Comment: It’s the subring of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ generated by $a$.

Comment: I really was looking for something like the title i was using for it.  It's something i use a great deal.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just not what it's called. I told you what the standard name for it is. If you go around talking about the "span of an equation", nobody is going to have any idea what you are talking about.